# How can i change jwt token without stop signalr connection?

Tags: websocket, jwt, header, signalr

I am using a signralr server and token authentication.

My clients made by typescript and connect to the server with signalr.

```
const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                       .withUrl("/MyServer", {accessTokenFactory: () => "MyToken"})
                       .configureLogging(LogLevel.Information)
                       .build();

connection.serverTimeoutInMilliseconds = 300000;
connection.start();
```

But if the token expired, I have to stop the connection and create a new connection with a new token to change the token.

Is there any way change the expired token to a new token without stoping connection.?